# SCVMM can't create windows 7 VM template with error 10619

Tags: hyper-v

SCVMM 2012

When to create VM template from a win7 VM, scvmm throws the following errors:

> Error (10619) The user name provided is not a valid local
>   administrator user name for this operating system.
>
> Recommended Action Provide a valid user name other than the built-in
>   Administrator account name and then try the operation again.
>
> Error (10666) Hardware changes while creating a template from a
>   virtual machine are not supported and were ignored.
>
> Recommended Action Make any hardware changes to the template after you
>   create the template.
>
> Solution: Remove the interACT default user and only left the
>   administrator account

Seems everything is ok and I tried for several times and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [post](http://cloudtidings.com/2009/10/27/scvmm-windows-7-template-creation-error-%E2%80%932147024864/):
1.Clean administrator password as blank
2.Stop Windows Media Sharing service